# Getting the rows in the "original" order in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a select query, that is working correctly, giving me a set of country names in one field. These country names are shortened, so my only field looks something like this:
rw,.

From another table, I can match these "country codes" with their real name ( like this: eg is s Egypt). The problem is, when I do that, the order of the countries will be alphabetical. Now I would like them to be in an order, they were before the second query. I know there is no order in a set or table in sql, but is is maybe still possible, to order these rows, in the original way?

Example:

rw,tz,ug,sd,eg    -- From the first query, i have these codes, for the countries in one field. I wrote a query ( with substring function ), that provides me a table, with one column and five rows, with the full name of the countries, like :

Egypt
Rwanda
Sudan
Tanzania
Uganda.

So is it possible, to get these in the order of their codes?

Comment: Add a column containing a sequence ID and increment it with each insert, then sort on that ID when you select.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "original" order in a relational table. Think of rows as balls in a basket. Which "order" do they have? The DBMS is free to return the rows in any order it likes unless you specify an `ORDER BY` statement.  You need to find an attribute that you can use to define an `ORDER BY` statement.

Comment: If the country code (`rw`) is included in the join, why can't you just order by that? It doesn't have to be included in the list of selected columns to be part of the `order by` clause, it just has to exist on (or be calculated from) one of the joined tables.

Comment: can you tell about the relationship between this tables??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select some_columns_here
from(
  select rownum rn, some_columns --original_query
  from ...
  ) a
  join Countries on (substring_condition)
order by rn;
```

But the order in the inner query can by assured only by an `order by` clause.